# Acessando dados em CSV

Tags: python, csv

O código é pra separar os valores de cada estado em listas diferentes, pra isso a variável 'o' muda toda
vez que a sigla do estado mudar e diz em qual lista os valores vão ficar. Ela funciona até a penultima mudança porém na ultima retorna o erro KeyError: 5596.
Não é problema no arquivo pois consigo acessar essa linha através de prints e de appends separados.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dados=pd.read_csv('salarios.csv',sep=',')

tamanho=len(dados)
anos=[]
for i in range(27):
    anos.append([])
o=0

sigla=dados['Sigla']

for i in range(tamanho):
    if sigla[i]!=sigla[i+1]:
        print(sigla[i])
        o=o+1`
```

Comment: Só quadrados, bom dia! Consegue disponibilizar o dataset? Abraço!

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, onde eu defini o tamanho do meu arquivo ele contou a linha das headers, quando vai separar o 'o' ele contava uma linha a mais que estava vazia

Comment: Ótimo então! Pedi o dataset para tentar resolver o problema de uma outra forma ja que você utiliza o pandas para armazenar a estrutura. Abraço!!